# Spring-boot + mail/Session JNDI resource = NoSuchBeanDefinitionException (JavaMailSender)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, jndi, tomcat8

I've been struggling for a couple of days (and no progress) with the configuration of the mail/Session as a JNDI resource (declared on the Tomcat side), to be picked up by an spring-boot app. The idea is to avoid having any critical information in the application, such as user/password data.

(**NOTE 1**: Credentials and conection through SMTP have been tested, with an application side configuration, hard-coded in the application.properties, so that is not a problem).

The current configuration I'm using is the following:

**server.xml** ($TOMCAT/conf)

```
<Resource
   name="mail/Session"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.mail.Session"
   username="user@test.com"
   password="XXX"
   mail.user="user@test.com"
   mail.password="XXX"
   mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
   mail.smtp.host="smtp.test.com"
   mail.smtp.auth="true"
   mail.smtp.port="587"/>
```

**context.xml** (webapp/META-INF)

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink 
        name="mail/Session"
        global="mail/Session"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"/>
</Context>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.jndi-name=java:comp/env/mail/Session
```

In the **pom.xml** I have the `spring-boot-starter-mail` dependency (as well as other necessary dependencies). And the class in which I'm inyecting the `JavaMailSender` bean is this one (simplified):

(**NOTE 2**: The spring-boot version used is 1.2.8.RELEASE)

```
@Service("emailService")
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMail(/* ... */) throws MessagingException {

        //Create message
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        helper.setFrom(fromAddress);
        helper.setTo(toAddress);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setText(body);

        //Send message
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

I understand that spring-boot autoconfiguration should create the JavaMailSender bean once it finds either jndiName or host,port,username,password... [spring.mail properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailProperties.java) (the later works when I set host, port, username and pasword in application.properties), but it throws the following stack when I use the jndiName option:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender com.testapp.service.EmailService.javaMailSender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender com.testapp.service.EmailService.javaMailSender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 31 more
```

I have a dataSource configured as a JNDI resource in the same way, and it works perfectly. Does the (mail)Session need a different aproach or am I missing something on it's configuration?

Comment: jndi has been added in Spring Boot 1.3 so it won't work with 1.2.

Comment: Damn... I understand that you refer to the JNDI support for the autoconfiguration of the JavaMailSender Bean (otherwise my app wouldn't be connecting to my DB). So does this mean that in order to initialize the bean I need to do it manually, whereas if I set the properties hard-coded in the app, the bean initialization is done automatically?  @.ô

Comment: Yes or upgrade spring boot :).

Comment: Will do, I just hope not to find too much problems on the process. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [**@m-deinum**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) pointed out in the comments, the problem wasn't the configuration, but the lack of JNDI support in spring-boot versions under 1.3.x

To solve the issue, I ended up heeding to *@m-deinum*'s tip and upgrading spring-boot from 1.2.8 to 1.3.5... dealing with some deprecated classes and new configurations and ready to go!